# Why does Inertia JS Form not work with vue. when I use errrors

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am currently stuck on a problem.

I have once an `IndexUserSettings.vue` this shows then the `IndexUserBillingDetail.vue`. In this vue it is checked if `create: boolean` == false or true. If true the `CreateUserBillingDetail.vue` is shown, if false `ListUserBillingDetail.vue` is shown.

Now the problem is as follows:
I have in the `CreateUserBillingDetail.vue` a form.

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="submit" class="grid grid-cols-1">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input class="p-2 border" id="name" v-model="form.name" />

    <label for="email">Email: </label>
    <input class="p-2 border" id="email" v-model="form.email" />

    <label for="street">Steet: </label>
    <input class="p-2 border" id="street" v-model="form.street" />

    <label for="street_addition">street Addition: </label>
    <input class="p-2 border" id="street_addition" v-model="form.street_addition" />

    <label for="postal_code">Postal Code: </label>
    <input class="p-2 border" id="postal_code" v-model="form.postal_code" />

    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <input class="p-2 border" id="city" v-model="form.city" />

    <label for="country">Country: </label>
    <input class="p-2 border" id="country" v-model="form.country" />

    <label for="vat_id">Vat ID: </label>
    <input class="p-2 border" id="vat_id" v-model="form.vat_id" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</template> 

<script>
import {Inertia} from "@inertiajs/inertia";
export default {
 name: "CreateUserBillingDetail",
 props: {
    errors: Object
},
data() {
    return {
        form: this.$inertia.form({
            name: null,
            email: null,
            street: null,
            street_addition: null,
            postal_code: null,
            city: null,
            country: null,
            vat_id: null
        })
    }
},
methods: {
    submit() {
        this.form.post(route('billingdetail.store'));
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now when I put `<div v-if="errors.name">{{ errors.name }}</div>` under each input the page no longer works.
Why does this happen?

I don't know how to do this. I want a user settings page to exist there the user can then set everything possible at the end. (Just see and create his billing details).

Do I have to write everything in the `UserSettingsController`? Currently I have both `UserSettingsController` + `UserBillingDetailController` but `UserBillingDetailController` is a completely different route `/billingdetail` and wants to have user Settings

Comment: what means no longer work? does console throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `error` Object is empty. To get validation errors of name field you can also use `form.errors.name`.
In contoller do validation as usual.